# Symfony 4, CORS and OPTION requests

Tags: php, symfony, cors, symfony4

- Just started a new project with Symfony 4 as API and Vue as frontend/app.
- Vue started complaining about CORS, so I started sending the required CORS headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).
- Then it started saying 'Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.'.

I hacked my API for now to force the status code to always be 200, but I'm looking for a long-term solution. Why is my API–built with Symfony 4–not respond with an OK status?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle -> it is easy to configure

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['^http://localhost:[0-9]+']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
            hosts: ['^api\.']
```

to respond manually you can read the definition in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

-> it basically states that an Option request will contain at least 3 headers:

- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Origin

For the Request to succeed you will have to respond to this request by returning and empty response with the following headers:

- Access-Control-Request-Methods - a list of methods you allow (ie "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin - the origin that was requested

or a non 2xx status if the cors request should be rejected

Comment: Right. I've seen this, but I'm against using a bundle to enable CORS. IMO that's just like using left-pad.

Comment: ok, then it means you have to respond to preflight requests with status ok and also return the origins you want to have + the headers you like - this is all the bundle takes care for you.

Comment: Exactly. And that's what I'm trying to do here. I just don't know what I should write to respond with status OK to preflight requests.

Comment: in an ideal world you would route the api requests through the same domain as your frontend (and then they would not require cors since it is the same origin)

Answer (score -1):

Since preflight requests use the OPTIONS request method, it's very likely that your webserver isn't set up to support them out of the box - many only support GET, POST and HEAD by default.

If that's the case, it may be as simple as changing a flag to allow OPTIONS requests. Well, and also returning the correct CORS response headers...